# ui Semantic apply dimmer in modal

Tags: css, angular, angular2-template, semantic-ui, simplemodal

I am using Angular 2 with ui Semantic to create the front-end of an application. I create my on own modal, so I am not using the modal code of ui Semantic, but I am using the style HTML CSS of then. Something like this:

```
<div class="ui modal">
  <div class="header">
    Some Header
  </div>
  <div class="description">
    <div class="ui header">
      Some description
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <div class="ui black deny button">
      Some action
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just copy the code from their example. But the point is, I would like to know how to apply the dimmer (make the background dark when I open the modal) using ui semantic. There's any way to do that?

Comment: hi, right now modal is launch in page ?

Comment: I have a boolean variable "active" to show the modal

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not added in JQUERY in correct way, check semantic ui examples how he does.Try with this queries

```
$('.ui.modal')
   .modal({
    blurring: true
 }).modal('show');
```

https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html#dimmer-variations

Comment: I am not using this JQUERY because I already have my own logic in typescript to show modal files.